# LTC4440 boosting in LTSpice, but not in reality

Tags: switching, mosfet-driver

I have a simple LTC4440-5 circuit in both LTSpice:

[image]

(R1 is just a load resistor, which isn't present in reality)

And here in the matrix, there's:
[image]

And:
[image]
(Note that a few parts are slightly different from simulation to reality: The inductor is a 5uH part, the diodes are both DB2W40300L shottkys, and the mosfet is an AO3400A. However, I can plug any mosfet and any diodes into the simulation and I can't break it.)

I have tried running at both 1mhz, and 100khz input frequency. In LTSpice, everything's peachy; in reality, I get no change from a floating gate.

Now, in the LTSpice simulation, I get this on the boosted gate pin:

[image]

And in reality, I get this:

[image]

The gate floats at ~3v.

The mosfet seems to be half on, as the TS/inductor pin is at 4v, no load.

I've confirmed that all the rails are as they should be; 5v VCC, 12v on the mosfet, etc. I've tried swapping out 4440s, tested all the diodes, changed input frequency, etc. Nada. I've tried to break the LTSpice simulation to get it to approximate the behavior, but I can't get it to not charge pump.

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Okay! Now we're getting somewhere. With a 100r resistor as a load in ltspice, I get a nice and stable charge pump. With a 130r resistor in reality, I get a sick 5khz oscillation in the charge pump:

[image]
(And zoomed)
[image]

Which... certainly wasn't the behavior I was expecting.

Comment: "R1 is just a load resistor, which isn't present in reality" there you have a pretty important difference

Comment: @PlasmaHH Do you think the load would affect the charge pump? I'll try it with a load now...

Comment: "I can't get it to not charge pump" - using logic to reduce this sentence I deduce that you "**can** get it to charge pump". What's with the incomplete circuit and the INA thing on the PCB. Very confusing.

Comment: @Andyaka The INA thing is a seperate part of the board. I took a terrible screenshot, let me try that again..

Comment: @Andyaka You are correct, as I *can* get the device to charge pump in the simulation.

Comment: Your bootstrap diode (D4) is maybe in backwards in reality?

Comment: @JohnD Good suggestion, but I've checked that...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Seems to work properly without any load in LTSpice, but I'll throw a load on anyhow

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well, you're right; load is an issue, though there's definitely something else going on here.

Comment: Well, it's not a synchronous buck, so you need to make sure D7 turns on every cycle to charge the bootstrap cap.  You're deeply discontinuous without a load and the switch node will ring up possibly not allowing enough time to charge the bootstrap cap.  With enough load the inductor average current will be high enough to keep D7 on a long time to ensure the bootstrap cap charges.

Comment: Change your simulation of the the load i.e. Vbat is a voltage sink with ESR or a precharged Cap of Vi of xx KFarads and ESR ~V/(Ah*3600) more  or less. I bet your 8.2uH choke is saturating

Comment: LTC4440’s pull-up has a peak output current of 2.4A and its pull-down has an output impedance of 1.5Ω.. so you must match load impedance better given that a battery is in milliohms and ZL(f) must not saturate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any wandering over this question in the future; I increased the charge pump cap value and it began running under 250ma load. Switched to a IRS25752, and it worked fine up to about 80% duty cycle, under 100ma load.

I ended up switching to a P-Channel mosfet and forgetting about the charge pump.